# Unity: Load a .ttf file as binary data

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a .ttf font file and I want to load it as binary data. I know I can load binary data as TextAsset in Unity. But this requires the file extensions to be ".fnt" or ".bytes" (few more extensions I know). If I change the file extension, I am able to load the file as binary data in TextAsset. But I dont want to change the file type.

1. Is there a method in Unity where I can load the .ttf file as binary data without changing the file
2. Is there a way I can load the .ttf file as Font Asset in Unity and then get the raw font data from the Font Asset?
3. Or some other way of loading the .ttf font as binary data?